# 64-bit .NET app using 64-bit OLEDBConnection fails writing excel spreadsheet with X080004005

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledbconnection

I have a Windows Service application  (C#, .NET 4.0 framework) that reads and writes excel spreadsheets. On a Windows 2012 server/SP2 it runs fine in 32-bit mode.

I have converted it to run in 64-bit mode. We removed the Access 2007 driver and installed the Microsoft Access Database Engine_x64 on the server. Booted the server afterwards just to be sure.

It can still read a spreadsheet. However, when it attempts to open another OLEDB connection for writing it errors out with an E_FAIL X80004005, a catch all error type, when opening the OLEDB connection.

The connection string used is:

```
 connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " +
                    "Data Source=" + responseExcelFile + ";"
                    + @"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;""";
```

Note I have tried it with `IMEX=1;HDR=YES`, though we got the same result, and those options seem to be oriented towards reading a spreadsheet, not writing one.

One thing that I realized is that the `responseExcelFile` in the connection string `data source` is just a file name at this point, and does not exist yet because we are going to write to it. However, the same code when using OLEDB 32 conformant connection string works fine. Also, note I get the same error whether the `responseExcelFile` to be written is an .xsl or .xslx.

It is not a permissions issue, the account under which the Service is running has full control of the directory in the file name. It is also not a duplicate file name, as it is time-stamped.

The actual error received is:

> ERROR ---  Bulk Query Export Process Error: NewBulkQueryProcessor:
>   IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005). at    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource'1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource'1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()    at
>   BulkQuery.BulkQueryOutputFile.CreateExcelSpreadsheet(String
>   responseExcelFile)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I recently encountered a similar problem, and the result was that a recent Windows Update caused the problem. Unfortunately all the info is at work and I can't find it after a quick search. Maybe that will help you to track down the issue...

Comment: uninstall Oct 11 updates
KB4041676 -- Windows 10 Version 1703/
KB4041691 -- Windows 10 Version 1607 and Windows Server 2016/
KB4041693 -- Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012/
KB4041681 -- Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2

Or change Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
if you only have office 2003 or need create a excel file，must install this
2007: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Comment: It is a double failure.  It first fell over on trying to initialize the ACE data provider and when it then tried to get a decent error message that failed as well.  So that is just shovels full of failure, the so common outcome of trying to use the 64-bit ACE provider.  Google "ace x64 e_fail", lots of hits.

Comment: @Pathum Anjana comment - We were unclear on how to interpret the advice. For Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2, are we to install or uninstall KB404161681.  The system administrator interpreted this to mean to install it, and after that, although opening an EXCEL 12.0 connection, we got the error message that the Microsoft.Jet.OleDB 4.0 component was not installed!

Comment: Another related problem. I had gotten the same code running fine on Windows7 in 32-bit mode using the Access 2007 engine. Suddenly, when trying to open the connection to write a new spreadsheet, I get the error "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only." I read some posts to add Mode=ReadWrite to the extended properties, but got the same error. Could this error also be due to a Windows 7 update?

Comment: I could close this because I believe I had a coding error and was invoking the wrong oledb version. So now the program can successfully create a spreadsheet, an .xlsx. The problem now is that Excel cannot read it when I copy it from the server back to my workstation. See the other post under my Identity. Thanks.